# Android Memory Allocator - Does memory need to be contiguous?

Tags: android, memory, memory-management

Does free heap space have to be contiguous for gralloc() calls to succeed?  Or can gralloc() return sparse free heap segments to satisfy a request? i.e. heap fragmentation

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that's up to the UMP device driver (which Gralloc merely interfaces with), but could be wrong. The driver/hardware may or may not have a way to map non contiguous UMP memory pages into a seemingly contiguous CPU address space. Does that make sense?

Comment: The concept makes sense, but knowing that there are additional layers of complexity doesn't solve the original question of whether a fragmented heap will cause gralloc() to fail.  It may or may not fail is something I already know ;)